# Retrospective Case Study with very small number of observations?

Tags: inference, descriptive-statistics, statistical-power, medicine

I am carrying out some research and am a novice to statistics, having done a 2 week module primarily focusing on parametric data and experimental design.

However, for my research I am doing a retrospective case study, on the hearing and speech outcomes of 3 groups of patients with 3 different ear conditions following a surgical intervention to improve their hearing. Ear condition being the independent variable, speech and hearing outcomes, the dependent variable.

The sample size is based on available data not a power calculation and each group has the following numbers, each group represents a different ear condition: 1) n = 10, 2) n = 5 and 3) n = 2.

I have been advised to do inferential stats, so have done the appropriate tests, but I wonder if inferential stats are geared toward an experimental design? The outcomes are also affected by many other demographic factors between patients such as the age they had the surgery, underlying cognitive ability and so forth — these were not controlled for owing to the type of study.

I also wonder as no power was calculated before (normally it is done following a pilot) but would you do a post hoc power calculation in this type of study?

I have also done descriptive stats, but I am quite uncertain about the use of inferential stats (Mann Whitney and t-tests) were appropriate to the data ... but I am unsure what inferences can be made on this type of study design?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is not a case control study- but a retrospective case study, data was collected retrospectively from files.